# Configure git settings in PyCharm IDE

Tags: git, pycharm

In Visual Studio, it is possible to set `global/local` user settings (name, email) through team explorer but I am having trouble finding this feature in PyCharm IDE. I have only found documentation to password configuration.

I am aware of possibility to use `git config --global/--local ...`, but I wanted to know if I can set this in IDE.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK Pycharm does not support these things. All you can do can be found in the CVS dialog (default shortcut: `Ctrl+Alt+S`).

You can use a GitHub account inside PyCharm and set up different things but you have to configure the global git settings elsewhere.

Comment: I am currently getting into 'full-usage' of IDE, not only using it as text editor and I was blown up by features that are available (refactoring, generating, etc) and I just couldn't believe that PyCharm doesn't support thing like `git config` through GUI. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Well it is not a full-blown Git GUI ;-)